# Filter an array in swift UISearchBar for multiple words in any order

Tags: swift

I have a UISearchBar and a tableView that displays an array of Food items, which have a variable called desc, that I am searching. My search functions can be seen below. Currently this works well to search case insensitively for exact string match and word order.

For example, the items I am searching have long, multiple word strings, such as "Milk, whole, 3.25% milkfat". If you search "milk", this item would be a result. However, if you search "whole milk", this item would not be a result. I am wondering how I can change my filterContentForSearchText method to work with multiple word searches. In the example, I would want a search for "whole milk" to include all results that had both of the words "whole" and "milk" in them - in any order.

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    if self.searchController?.searchBar.text.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF32StringEncoding) > 0 {

        let searchBarText = self.searchController!.searchBar.text

        self.filterContentForSearchText(searchBarText)

        // Reload a table with results.
        self.searchResultsController?.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func filterContentForSearchText(searchBarText : String) {
    self.filteredFoods = allFoods.filter({(food : Food) -> Bool in
        let stringMatch = food.desc.rangeOfString(searchBarText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)

        return (stringMatch != nil)
    })
}
```

Comment: You're making assumptions about the content. You can split by whitespace if you want to threat each word as a search parameter, and then look for matches. Alternatively, you can implement some of the more advanced search algorithms like [fuzzy search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching)